# accessing elements in json

Tags: javascript, html, json

Below is my JSON tree. How to access `Typedefinition` attribute in the given tree and frame if condition for all the Typedefinition. I have to traverse the tree find

```
if (typedefinition == "ciu'){//do something}
else if(typedef == Tank )
else if( hostport) 
else if( fieldport)
```

and do something for each if. I have to traverse the tree and make a condition like this.

```
{
    "Resp_Data":
    {
        "SiteElements":
        [
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Gauge00",
                        "ID": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "GAUGE",
                        "ID": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2003",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "00"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2006",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2004",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "54"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9007",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9703",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections":
                [
                    {
                        "SourceElementID": "2",
                        "DestinationElementID": "1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Tank1",
                        "ID": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "TANK",
                        "ID": "3"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities": "",
                "Connections":
                [
                    {
                        "SourceElementID": "5",
                        "DestinationElementID": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "SourceElementID": "2",
                        "DestinationElementID": "1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "CIU1",
                        "ID": "3"

                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "CIU",
                        "ID": "4"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "7050",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9006",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "7050",
                        "Index": "2",
                        "Value": "8"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "7050",
                        "Index": "3",
                        "Value": "7"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3037",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "\/dev\/ttyS1",
                        "ID": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "CIU1",
                        "ID": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "HOSTPORT",
                        "ID": "5"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5022",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "9600"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5027",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5020",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5024",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5034",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5025",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5019",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5006",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5012",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "3302"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5012",
                        "Index": "2",
                        "Value": "2801"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5013",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "10000"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5013",
                        "Index": "2",
                        "Value": "100"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5014",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5014",
                        "Index": "2",
                        "Value": "30000"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5006",
                        "Index": "2",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5006",
                        "Index": "3",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5005",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5007",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5009",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5008",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5011",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5011",
                        "Index": "2",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9015",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9016",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "\/dev\/ttyS0",
                        "ID": "5"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "CIU1",
                        "ID": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "FIELDPORT",
                        "ID": "6"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3504",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "40"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3507",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "9000"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3510",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9011",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "7"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9012",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "CIU1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3501",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3502",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3503",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3505",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3500",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "BPM-GPU"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9013",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "3"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections":
                [
                    {
                        "SourceElementID": "5",
                        "DestinationElementID": "2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "CIU2",
                        "ID": "6"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "CIU",
                        "ID": "4"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities": "",
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Tank2",
                        "ID": "7"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "TANK",
                        "ID": "3"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities": "",
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Tank3",
                        "ID": "8"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "TANK",
                        "ID": "3"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities": "",
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Gauge11",
                        "ID": "9"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "GAUGE",
                        "ID": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2011",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "11"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2012",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2013",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "C"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9008",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2016",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "54"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Gauge22",
                        "ID": "10"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "GAUGE",
                        "ID": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2003",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "22"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2004",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2006",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9007",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9703",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "54"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Gauge33",
                        "ID": "11"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "GAUGE",
                        "ID": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2011",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "33"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2012",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2013",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "C"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9008",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2016",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "54"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Gauge44",
                        "ID": "12"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "GAUGE",
                        "ID": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2011",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "44"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2012",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2013",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "C"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9008",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2016",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2003",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "44"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2004",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2006",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9007",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9703",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "54"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Gauge55",
                        "ID": "13"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "GAUGE",
                        "ID": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2011",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "55"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2012",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2013",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "C"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9008",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "2016",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "5",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "54"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections": ""
            },
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "\/dev\/ttyS1",
                        "ID": "14"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "CIU1",
                        "ID": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "TypeDefinition": "FIELDPORT",
                        "ID": "6"
                    }
                ],
                "Entities":
                [
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3501",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9011",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "7"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3503",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3502",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3505",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9012",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "CIU1"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "9013",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3504",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "40"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3507",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "9000"
                    },
                    {
                        "EntityId": "3510",
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Value": "2"
                    }
                ],
                "Connections": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I clipped a few elements from the end to make the post fit in the 30,000 character limit with the proper code formatting. I don't suppose they are relevant for the question.

Comment: You [asked this today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743790/accessing-particular-attribute-in-json). Didnt helped that?

Comment: ya mumble it dint help i got "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Resp_Data.SiteElements' is null or not an object" an error..now my requirement has been changed i have access the typedef element from json without parsing it

Comment: "Without parsing it"? Why?

Comment: ya already its an json data....so its enough we track it as is is...without parsing....so jus having the json data help me to trach typedef and fram condition

Comment: so can anyone help me with the perfect coding please....i wan it as sooner as possible

Comment: I don't think "parsing" means what you think it means.

Comment: No...just leave of parsing....suggest me the code to access typedef in the json tree and frame condition for it...becos am getting error like  Resp_Data.SiteElements[0].SiteElementDef is null or not an object for the codes suggested by few ppl...pls do help me with perfect code...i need it very badly

Comment: If this is the error you are getting, then the structure of your data is not like you posted. In any case, this question is too localized. How to access arrays and objects is basic JS knowledge. Have a look at the link in my previous comment and maybe read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide. And how quickly you need a solution is not our concern, we are doing this voluntarily, we don't get paid.

Comment: i posted the structure correctly i checked it out too

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var result=myJSONObject.Resp_Data.SiteElements[0].SiteElementDef[0].TypeDefinition
```

assign your above json to myJSONObject then try this code.

[Refer this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539797/complex-json-nesting-of-objects-and-arrays)

Comment: am getting an error like Resp_Data.SiteElements[0].SiteElementDef is null or not an object

Comment: then i think its better to do by spliting. try this and tell did you got array Resp_Data.SiteElements[0]

Comment: ya i tried this...same error am getting

Comment: can u suggest me the perfect code ..pls am badly in need of it..

Comment: myJSONObject.Resp_Data.SiteElements[0].SiteElementDef this is also not working?

Comment: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: just try the above else we can try another way. In which language u r working? java, php have good libraries

Comment: which code is working?

Comment: did you assign your json string to a variable?

Comment: var myJSONObject={
    "Resp_Data":
    {
        "SiteElements":
        [
            {
                "SiteElementDef":
                [
                    {
                        "SiteElementName": "Gauge00",
                        "ID": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Parent": "",
                        "ID": ""
                    },.................

Comment: then myJSONObject.Resp_Data.SiteElements[0].SiteElementDef[0].TypeDefinition

Comment: ya i did it the same way as u did

Comment: am getting the error 'myJSONObject' is undefined if i do as u did

Comment: myJSONObject.Resp_Data.SiteElements[SiteElementDef][0].TypeDefinition

Comment: 'Resp_Data.SiteElements' is null or not an object same error

Comment: Is it better to use for loop by accessing with keys

Comment: you use loop also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431641/javascript-access-nested-values-in-json-data-using-dynamic-variable-names

Comment: var siteElements = data["Resp_Data"]["SiteElements"]; for(var i = 0; i < siteElements.length; i++) { var siteElementDef = siteElements[i]["SiteElementDef"]; var siteElementName = ''; for(var j = 0; j < siteElementDef.length; j++) { if(siteElementDef[j]["SiteElementName"]) { siteElementName = siteElementDef[j]["SiteElementName"]; } else if(siteElementDef[j]["TypeDefinition"] == 'CIU') { alert(siteElementName); } } } is this correct this is also not working

Comment: are using any language? means java,php etc?

Comment: ya html n javascript <script> function callme(){var data = {above json structure};then the above which i sent comes}<body><input type ="buton" onClick = "callme()" value = "pressme"/>

Comment: read this and try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158339/complex-json-and-tutorials                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539797/complex-json-nesting-of-objects-and-arrays

Comment: no no...only javascript html

Comment: ask to anyone less i dont know why it is not working

Comment: callme() have json structure then where is your code to access TypeDefinition

Comment: @user2050531: You have to work this out on your own. People are trying to help you based on the information you provide. But then you keep repeating that it does not work because some property is not defined. You don't provide more information though. We cannot remotely debug your code, you have to do this yourself. If you are not able to, then your problem is much bigger than just accessing this data structure. We cannot teach you programming here, you have to know at least the basics.

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
if (!obj.TypeDefinition) {
  // ..
}
else if (obj.TypeDefinition == "GAUGE") { 
  // ..
} // ...
```

Comment: my code goes like this<script> function callme(){ var data =[{json tree}] //wat shd i do here now to asccess typedef and frame condition//</script><body><input type ="button" onClick = "callme()" value ="pressme"/>

Comment: <script> function callme(){ var data =[{json tree}] ; //wat shd i do here now to asccess typedef and frame condition//                 </script><body><input type ="button" onClick = "callme()" value ="pressme"/>

Comment: the above json tree which i have mentioned

Comment: your json is a obj, so let's call it `obj` then `obj.Resp_Data.SiteElements[0].SiteElementDef[2]TypeDefinition == "GAUGE"` is `true`

Comment: am getting the erroor 'Resp_Data.SiteElements' is null or not an object

Comment: how to access the typedef with keys

Comment: how to continue this for my json obj                                 for(key in jsonObj) {
   if(jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     //do something with the values
     // jsonObj[key] 
   }
} where my json obj is assigned to jsonObj